# Google Map Geocoding not returning lat/long for a valid complete address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am facing a weird issue with Google Maps Geocoding API v3. It works fine for all other addresses that i have tried so far but it's giving me an issue with the following address.

35 & 36, Rajiv Gandhi Infotech Park,  Pune, 411057,  India
OR
Plot No 35/36,Rajiv Gandhi Infotech Park,Phase 1,MIDC,Hinjawadi,Pune,411057,India
Even for: Rajiv Gandhi Infotech Park,  Pune, 411057,  India

The GeocoderStatus is ZERO_RESULTS.

Below is the code snippet.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              geocoder.geocode({
                  'address' : address
              },
              function (results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                     ....
                   }
                   else{...}
```

However, the **same address is returning a valid** lat/long with 'OK' status in **json result** at the below link.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=35&36+Rajiv+Gandhi+Infotech+Park,+Pune,+411057,+India&sensor=true

Can anyone please tell me what is the cause of this issue and its resolution?

Comment: Read the data you get from the link - it's returning locations from all over the world, but none of them are in India. I guess if you've got your map centred in India, none of them would be visible. It's pretty weird that the API doesn't find it though - Google Maps finds the address just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that particular address is recently added to Google's database.

> **Why do the Google Maps APIs Geocoders provide different locations than Google Maps?**
>
> The API geocoder and Google Maps geocoder sometimes use different data sets (depending on the country). The API geocoder occasionally gets updated with new data, so you can expect to see results changing or improving over time.
>
> taken from: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#geocoder_differences

Comment: When I investigated further on this issue, i found out that the reason is not that this address is new or not in geocoder db but the issue is the **postal code**. When i remove the postal code, it gives me the correct lat/long coordinates. Now, as far as i could see, this is happening with addresses of India only. One solution would be to remove this postal code but they would not return precise results for other addresses. Moreoever, why is this happening at all when geocoding api accepts the postal code in the input address?